# How to set a value of JESD

Tags: fpga, adc, datasheet, protocol

I'm trying to connect an ADC with an FPGA via JESD, but I'm not able to set a relevant parameter on in. [Here](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/jesd204/v6_0/pg066-jesd204.pdf) is the link of the datasheet, where in the page 92 there are several parameters. In order to configure some of them, in the page 28 of the same datasheet, there is the description of which address corresponds to each parameter. Anyway, the Number of samples per convertor per frame cycle is a parameter that I need to modify (also named as "S" in the datasheet), but I can't. How would it be possible to modify it?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is it a calculated value defined by other parameters (that can be programmed) hence it is read-only?

Comment: It is a value derived from other parameters but just in the [ADC](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slas989c/slas989c.pdf) as it can be seen in the page 39. Anyway, in the FPGA side, it must be configured to establish the link. I was able to configure the parameters L, F and K, but not S. @andy-aka

Comment: Do you even need to set that one?  Isn't octets per frame enough?  The interpretation of the framed octets into samples is done outside the core, correct?

Comment: That's it. I didn't set it before because I thought that it was not necessary. Moreover, for D=4 it should take a value of S=2, while for D=8 and D=16 it should be S=1. All of them work correctly without specifically setting it, but as I need S=5 for D=32, and it is the only one not working, I thought that it could be due to the S parameter. Nevermind, I set the parameters correctly in the ADC part, so as the FPGA part, and it is not working. So I cannot think of any other reason why this is the only decimation ratio which makes the connection fail. @alex-forencich

Answer (score 0):

I think that the number of samples per frame setting ("S") is irrelevant in the operation of the core itself.  You'll need to set the correct number of octets per frame ("F"), then write your own logic to slice and dice the samples out of the frames.  See page 53 of the Xilinx UG.